# Is it a bad practice to randomly-generate test data?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, fixtures

Since I've started using rspec, I've had a problem with the notion of fixtures.  My primary concerns are this:

1. I use testing to reveal surprising behavior.  I'm not always clever enough to enumerate every possible edge case for the examples I'm testing.  Using hard-coded fixtures seems limiting because it only tests my code with the very specific cases that I've imagined.  (Admittedly, my imagination is also limiting with respect to which cases I test.)
2. I use testing to as a form of documentation for the code.  If I have hard-coded fixture values, it's hard to reveal what a particular test is trying to demonstrate.  For example:

   ```
   describe Item do
     describe '#most_expensive' do
       it 'should return the most expensive item' do
         Item.most_expensive.price.should == 100
         # OR
         #Item.most_expensive.price.should == Item.find(:expensive).price
         # OR
         #Item.most_expensive.id.should == Item.find(:expensive).id
       end
     end
   end
   ```

   Using the first method gives the reader no indication what the most expensive item is, only that its price is 100.  All three methods ask the reader to take it on faith that the fixture `:expensive` is the most expensive one listed in `fixtures/items.yml`.  A careless programmer could break tests by creating an `Item` in `before(:all)`, or by inserting another fixture into `fixtures/items.yml`.  If that is a large file, it could take a long time to figure out what the problem is.

One thing I've started to do is add a `#generate_random` method to all of my models.  This method is only available when I am running my specs.  For example:

```
class Item
  def self.generate_random(params={})
    Item.create(
      :name => params[:name] || String.generate_random,
      :price => params[:price] || rand(100)
    )
  end
end
```

(The specific details of how I do this are actually a bit cleaner.  I have a class that handles the generation and cleanup of all models, but this code is clear enough for my example.)  So in the above example, I might test as follows.  A warning for the feint of heart: my code relies heavily on use of `before(:all)`:

```
describe Item do
  describe '#most_expensive' do
    before(:all) do
      @items = []
      3.times { @items << Item.generate_random }
      @items << Item.generate_random({:price => 50})
    end

    it 'should return the most expensive item' do
      sorted = @items.sort { |a, b| b.price <=> a.price }
      expensive = Item.most_expensive
      expensive.should be(sorted[0])
      expensive.price.should >= 50      
    end
  end
end
```

This way, my tests better reveal surprising behavior.  When I generate data this way, I occasionally stumble upon an edge case where my code does not behave as expected, but which I wouldn't have caught if I were only using fixtures.  For example, in the case of `#most_expensive`, if I forgot to handle the special case where multiple items share the most expensive price, my test would occasionally fail at the first `should`.  Seeing the non-deterministic failures in AutoSpec would clue me in that something was wrong.  If I were only using fixtures, it might take much longer to discover such a bug.

My tests also do a slightly better job of demonstrating in code what the expected behavior is.  My test makes it clear that sorted is an array of items sorted in descending order by price.  Since I expect `#most_expensive` to be equal to the first element of that array, it's even more obvious what the expected behavior of `most_expensive` is.

So, is this a bad practice?  Is my fear of fixtures an irrational one?  Is writing a `generate_random` method for each Model too much work?  Or does this work?

Comment: The line "3.times { @items  50})" doesn't look right.

Comment: And now, a mere 58 months later, I respond... It doesn't look right because it has "&lt;&lt;" in it... but not properly escaped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an answer to your second point:

> (2) I use testing to as a form of documentation for the code. If I have hard-coded fixture values, it's hard to reveal what a particular test is trying to demonstrate.

I agree. Ideally spec examples should be understandable by themselves. Using fixtures is problematic, because it splits the pre-conditions of the example from its expected results.

Because of this, many RSpec users have stopped using fixtures altogether. Instead, construct the needed objects in the spec example itself.

```
describe Item, "#most_expensive" do
  it 'should return the most expensive item' do
    items = [
      Item.create!(:price => 100),
      Item.create!(:price => 50)
    ]

    Item.most_expensive.price.should == 100
  end
end
```

If your end up with lots of boilerplate code for object creation, you should take a look at some of the many test object factory libraries, such as [factory_girl](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/), [Machinist](http://github.com/notahat/machinist/tree/master), or [FixtureReplacement](http://replacefixtures.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Is the FixtureReplacement link broken?

Comment: Lots of excellent answers, but this one cut to the chase -- there's a better way to do what I want to do, and my test data doesn't have to be 'random' anymore.

Comment: bobocopy: It seems so. Odd, I think it was working yesterday. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 15):

I'm surprised no one in this topic or in the one [Jason Baker linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256065/testing-with-random-inputs-best-practices) mentioned 
[Monte Carlo Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method).  That's the only time I've extensively used randomized test inputs.  However, it was very important to make the test reproducible, by having a constant seed for the random number generator for each test case.

Comment: +1 for the reproducible comment. Controlling the random generator's initial state is very important. If you find a weird behavior, you're going to want to try it again.

Comment: another +1 for the reproducible.

Comment: Thirded.  When I've used randomized testing I always add a way to report and set the seed.  Although in general I try to avoid relying on randomization...

Comment: I would log the generated seed instead of having a constant seed.

Answer (score 5):

We thought about this a lot on a recent project of mine. In the end, we settled on two points:

- Repeatability of test cases is of paramount importance. If you must write a random test, be prepared to document it extensively, because if/when it fails, you will need to know exactly why.
- Using randomness as a crutch for code coverage means you either don't have good coverage or you don't understand the domain enough to know what constitutes representative test cases. Figure out which is true and fix it accordingly.

In sum, randomness can often be more trouble than it's worth. Consider carefully whether you're going to be using it correctly before you pull the trigger. We ultimately decided that random test cases were a bad idea in general and to be used sparingly, if at all.

Comment: I use random test data extensively. I've never had a single situation where it was more trouble than it was worth. My random tests are simple enough that I can always tell exactly why they fail. I *have* had random testing reveal mistaken assumptions in my code. Random test cases are a much better idea than hard-coded ones and should be used wherever possible. Never hard-code your test data if you can avoid it -- that's cheating at solitaire.

Comment: Also, you don't necessary need a repeatable random number generator. A dump of the value in the failed test case works just as well.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good information has already been posted, but see also: [Fuzz Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing).  Word on the street is that Microsoft uses this approach on a lot of their projects.

Comment: I'm glad someone brought this up. Fuzz Testing is hugely useful, but note that random testing should be *in addition* to repeatable tests.

Comment: @vasi If "random" includes pseudo-random, then it does not conflict with repeatability. How about logging the seed?

Answer (score 1):

My experience with testing is mostly with simple programs written in C/Python/Java, so I'm not sure if this is entirely applicable, but whenever I have a program that can accept any sort of user input, I always include a test with random input data, or at least input data generated by the computer in an unpredictable way, because you can never make assumptions about what users will enter.  Or, well, you *can*, but if you do then some hacker who doesn't make that assumption may well find a bug that you totally overlooked. Machine-generated input is the best (only?) way I know of to keep human bias completely out of the testing procedures. Of course, in order to reproduce a failed test you have to do something like saving the test input to a file or printing it out (if it's text) before running the test.

Answer (score 1):

Random testing is a bad practice a long as you don't have a solution for the *oracle problem*, i.e., determining which is the expected outcome of your software given its input.

If you solved the oracle problem, you can get one step further than simple random input generation. You can choose input distributions such that specific parts of your software get exercised more than with simple random.

You then switch from random testing to statistical testing.

```
if (a > 0)
    // Do Foo
else (if b < 0)
    // Do Bar
else
    // Do Foobar
```

If you select `a` and `b` randomly in `int` range, you exercise `Foo` 50% of the time, `Bar` 25% of the time and `Foobar` 25% of the time. It is likely that you will find more bugs in `Foo` than in `Bar` or `Foobar`.

If you select `a` such that it is negative 66.66% of the time, `Bar` and `Foobar` get exercised more than with your first distribution. Indeed the three branches get exercised each 33.33% of the time.

Of course, if your observed outcome is different than your expected outcome, you have to log everything that can be useful to reproduce the bug.

Comment: You don't need statistical testing for this -- just a measurable relation between your input and your output.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a look at Machinist:

> **http://github.com/notahat/machinist/tree/master**

Machinist will generate data for you, but it is repeatable, so each test-run has the same random data.

You could do something similar by seeding the random number generator consistently.

Comment: Do you need to have ActiveRecord/Rails in order to use machinist?

Comment: I believe it does depend on ActiveRecord, but you can use it outside of Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Use of random test data is an excellent practice -- hard-coded test data only tests the cases you explicitly thought of, whereas random data flushes out your implicit assumptions that might be wrong.

I highly recommend using Factory Girl and ffaker for this. (Never use Rails fixtures for anything under any circumstances.)

Answer (score 0):

One problem with randomly generated test cases is that validating the answer should be computed by code and you can't be sure it doesn't have bugs :)

Comment: The tests and code test each other. If your test has bugs, you'll quickly find out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might also see this topic:  [Testing with random inputs best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256065/testing-with-random-inputs-best-practices).

Answer (score 0):

Effectiveness of such testing largely depends on quality of random number generator you use and on how correct is the code that translates RNG's output into test data.

If the RNG never produces values causing your code to get into some edge case condition you will not have this case covered. If your code that translates the RNG's output into input of the code you test is defective it may happen that even with a good generator you still don't hit all the edge cases.

How will you test for that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with randomness in test cases is that the output is, well, random.

The idea behind tests (especially regression tests) is to check that nothing is broken.

If you find something that is broken, you need to include that test every time from then on, otherwise you won't have a consistent set of tests. Also, if you run a random test that works, then you need to include that test, because its possible that you may break the code so that the test fails.

In other words, if you have a test which uses random data generated on the fly, I think this is a bad idea. If however, you use a set of random data, WHICH YOU THEN STORE AND REUSE, this may be a good idea. This could take the form of a set of seeds for a random number generator.

This storing of the generated data allows you to find the 'correct' response to this data.

So, I would recommend using random data to explore your system, but use defined data in your tests (which may have originally been randomly generated data)

Answer (score 0):

Like everything in software engineering, it depends.

The biggest argument people use against it, is that it breaks the test cases being deterministic. However, that's not a problem really, as long as your test cases can **fail deterministically**. The problem is when your tests become **flaky** due to random data.

In practice there's several good cases to random data:

- Solve conflicts related to your data. E.g. a fixture factory solving unique constraint automatically for a field by using a random-generated UUID.
- Maintainable test cases due to reduced boilerplate. When you want to test x, let's focus on just x and not its dependencies.
- Fuzzy testing. In which case you **want** random combinations of data and even noise.